# Passing html field value to JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

When trying to get the data from the HTML field, I receive a NaN error.

If in the code the numeric value is added, the query works when testing, and the alert is displayed with the returned value.

```
<label>Monthly Cost</label>
<input type="number" name="pricepermonth" id="pricepermonth" class="form-control" >
<label>ProRata Cost</label>
<input type="text" name="remainingprice" id="remainingprice" class="form-control" >
```

```
var dt = new Date();  
month = dt.getMonth();
day   = dt.getDate();
year  = dt.getFullYear();


if(month == 11)
var nextMonth = new Date(year+1,0,1);
else
var nextMonth = new Date(year,month+1,1);

var today = new Date(year,month,day);

var remain = (nextMonth.getTime() - today.getTime())/1000;  
remain = remain/(60*60*24);
totaldays = day+remain;     
var priceperday = pricepermonth/totaldays;

var remainingprice = priceperday.toFixed(2)*remain;
alert(remainingprice);
return remainingprice;
}

var pricepermonth = $('#pricepermonth').data();
code(pricepermonth);
```

The expected result is that when a numeric value is added to the Monthly Cost field, this then triggers the query, of which will then output the value as a pro rata cost in the second field.

The only error message I get is the NaN (not a number) error.

Comment: Where is the triggering event on your code?

Comment: I think we are missing some code?

Comment: `$('#pricepermonth').data` should probably be `$('#pricepermonth').data()`, although it seems a little redundant as `#pricepermonth` does not appear to actually have any data. When does your logic run? Also what is the `code()` function doing?

Comment: @chrisBinstead At what line you get error

Comment: Sorry I see there is some line missing form the top part of the jquery: $('#pricepermonth').change(function() {
    $('#remainingprice').val($(this).val());
});

function code(pricepermonth){

Comment: code() function is working out a pro rata cost. Some code is missing from the top of the jquery section: $('#pricepermonth').change(function() {
    $('#remainingprice').val($(this).val());
});

function code(pricepermonth){

Comment: @satavelke The error only comes up once a numeric value is added, sorry I am not a developer and I am new to coding. If I change this "var pricepermonth = $('#pricepermonth').data();
code(pricepermonth);" to this "var pricepermonth = 80;
code(pricepermonth);" the code works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using an input you should use [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) to:

> Get the content of the value attribute of the first matched element

In your code:

```
var pricepermonth = $('#pricepermonth').val();
```

[.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) it's used for something else:

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return
>   the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements.

In another words it's useful for associating various objects, strings, arrays, etc with a DOM element

Comment: thanks for the input, I have made the change, now the returned val is 0, it looks like it is not fetching the .val. I have setup a jsfiddle to test from: http://jsfiddle.net/sbc964z7/

Comment: Cool, with the updated code, I have added it to the app I am building, the cost per month is based on data fetched via AJAX, and is working, now just to see how to push the .val instead of an alert window to the field for the Pro Rata rate.